# C++ static array declaration

Tags: c++, arrays

When I run the following code I get a stack overflow. How is it possible? I thought if I define an array outside of main it will be static and I won't have memory problems? What can I do against it?

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define dim1 14001
#define dim2 14001
#define dim4 8

double large_array[dim1][dim2][dim4];

int main()
{
  large_array[30][6][5] = 1337;
  printf("%lf\t",large_array[30][6][5]);
}
```

Comment: Does your machine have the 12 GB memory that this array would require?

Comment: @amchacon No, it's ~12 GB. A `double` is 8 bytes long

Comment: @amchacon: Do the math again. And additionally, remember that `double` is bigger than one byte.

Comment: @Holger More like 11-ish.

Comment: @Holger: Being outside of main doesn't make the array `static`. However, I don't think `static` is the right word for what you mean to ask about.

Comment: @Hurkyl: "static" has several meanings. This has static storage duration.

Comment: 12Gb memory required for this. You'll need to (a) compile it as a 64-bit application and (b) either buy more physical memory (fast) or `mmap` it and page in the parts you need as you need them (slow). Alternatively rent yourself some time on AWS x.large compute node at $0.60/hr :)

Comment: would it be okay if I provide code that runs on C++ but not on C?

Comment: @Jerry Goal: absolutely!

Comment: Best choice is containers like std::vector or std::valarray that allocates data storage in heap even when the container is automatic storage duration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

3-D global array you declared consumes too much memory (~1043456KB.i.e..~1GB) on `heap` while initialising at compile time, which is why your program is giving overflow problem.
One intuitive way to handle this problem is to use multidimensional `map` STL instead of Multidimensional Global array.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<map>
/*#define dim1 14001
#define dim2 14001
#define dim4 8
double large_array[dim1][dim2][dim4];
*/
using namespace std;
map<double, map<double,map<double,double> > > large_array;
int main()
{
  large_array[30][6][5] = 1337;
  printf("%lf\t",large_array[30][6][5]);
}
```

Comment: @ Jerry: great, that works, thanks! so how much memory is allocated to this array if I don't even give the dimensions in advance?

Comment: It's not an array.it is hash map.you don't have to specify any size.see this http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/

Answer (score 2):

One problem this has is that it's very likely that the place where the compiler wants to store the array doesn't have room to fit that much memory -- in some environments, very large allocations *must* be done on the heap, e.g. with `malloc`, `new`, or other similar means (or implicitly through those means, e.g. as done internally by `std::vector`).

Comment: could you maybe give ma a very simple example?

Comment: How malloc,new is different from that global array.i.e..both are globally stored, so does it really make sense.

Comment: Actually, I figured out it works when I use malloc. But I need a for-loop, which I cannot do outside main.

Comment: @Jerry: I'm unsure on the fine details, but I can confirm the end result from experience. I think it has something to do with how executables get loaded, with the array going in the data segment rather than on the heap or somesuch.

Comment: @Hurkyl: could you please provide a minimal example of that?

Comment: @Holger: What is "that"? I'm not sure what you're asking for that isn't just writing a program that has a big array and make it bigger until it crashes on loading, then replace it with a pointer that gets allocated with `new` to make an array of the same size. If your system exhibits the behavior I'm describing above, then that version won't crash.

Comment: @Hurkyl: let's rephrase: with both, malloc and new I can define a larger array. But both I cannot use outside main, so it will not be global, right?

Comment: @Holger: Globals can have initializers, so nothing is stopping you from initializing them there with `new`. But even if you want to do the allocation inside of main, you can still declare the pointer in global scope.

Comment: @Hurkyl: we can only create a 3D dynamic array using loop but that runs inside the main() and we have to specify its boundaries, so in that case system crashes too.here's the code http://ideone.com/vpPfow Holger: are you sure it worked with malloc?

Comment: @Jerry: If two dimensions are fixed in the type rather than pointers, you can use just a single `new` statement. For `***` you can always make the initializer a function call to a function that allocates everything correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The maximum size of an statically allocated array is determined by the amount of memory that a program can access. On a 32-bit system, the maximum amount of memory that can be addressed by a pointer is 2^32 bytes which is 4 gigabytes. The actual limit may be less, depending on operating system implementation details and compiler implementation choices.

As [interjay](https://stackoverflow.com/users/189205/interjay) said in comment, your allocation requires quite higher amount of space.

In C++, you should use the provided containers like vector or the boost multi dimensional arrays to handle such cases.

Comment: thanks, I understand. Is there a way to solve this besides buying a new computer?

Comment: In windows, it's 2gb.

Comment: @Holger Compile in 64 bits.

Comment: @Holger, in C++ you should use the provided containers like vector or the boost multi dimensional arrays.

Comment: *"The actual limit may be less, depending on operating system implementation details."* - there are also compiler implementation choices to consider... the C++11 Standard's recommended minimum object size to support is only 262 144 bytes (from Annex B).  Specific implementations are required to document their actual support.

Comment: @TonyD, yeah, that's also very true. I am editing my answer. Thanks.

Comment: @Holger Do you set a non-zero value to the vast majority of elements in your array(s)? If most are zero, then you could look into sparse data structures which exploit the "zero-ness" of your data, e.g. libraries for sparse matrices.

Comment: @ nils, well about 1/3 is non-zero